# Firefox not reading css

Tags: html, css, firefox

Basically the title, tried opening a page on firefox, from localhost (WAMP) which has an external css file and its not loading.
Here is the header info:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="..\include\site.css" id="style">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The css has been validated as has the html file, both have no errors. The css works in IE and Chrome. Looked for solutions elsewhere but couldnt find anything that helped.

Any suggestions?

Thank-you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the slashes:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="..\include\site.css" id="style">
```

to:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="../include/site.css" id="style">
```

Comment: Worked thank-you! Weird though, is that how its meant to be? Seen examples of both scattered about.

Comment: I've always used the slashes the way i've done it in my answer and never got any trouble. I suppose its a OS thing but i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: You use backward slashes when following a folder type structure on your computer like `C:\user\name\documents`, but you need to use forward slashes in an `href`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll just explain this in a little more detail, so that there is no confusion to you or anyone else who stumbles on here :

`Unix` and its variants have always used the forward slash (/) to denote filesystem hierarchy. On the other hand, `Windows` borrows its filesystem delimiter, the backslash (), from `MS-DOS` which happens to be its predecessor.

The Internet URL path separator was chosen to be the slash since most of the developers of the time were familiar with `Unix` standards. The `Unix` slash as path separator is usually considered to be the canonical separator. The forward slash(/) is the de facto path separator on web-based systems.

IN your case, the link tag should be :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="../include/site.css" id="style">
```

Hope this helps!!!